# How to configure Shopify Hydrogen V2 with LESS/CSS modules

Tags: css-modules, shopify-template, shopify-hydrogen

I am trying to configure Shopify Hydrogen V2 with LESS (or at least CSS) modules, so I can encapsulate component styles that are only loaded on demand.

**Desired usage:**

```
import styles from "./style.module.less"

const ComponentName = () => (
  <div className={styles.ComponentName}>Content</div>
);

export default ComponentName;
```

So far I only found [this in the documentation](https://shopify.github.io/hydrogen-v1/tutorials/css-support/import-css-in-rsc), but it does not seem to be up-to-date: it says you should edit the Vite config file with an experimental feature, but it seems like Hydrogen V2 does not even use Vite anymore as they [direct you to remove it](https://shopify.dev/docs/custom-storefronts/hydrogen/migrate-hydrogen-remix#step-2-remove-vite).

Have anyone configured it to work? Is there any source I missed?

Answer (score 0):

To get access to the CSS bundle, first install the @remix-run/css-bundle package

npm install @remix-run/css-bundle@1.19.1 or @remix-run/css-bundle@2.0.0

> ensure that the version is the same as your @remix-run/react version else it wont work.

root.tsx

```
import { cssBundleHref } from "@remix-run/css-bundle";
 import {type LinksFunction} from '@shopify/remix-oxygen';

 export const links: LinksFunction = () => {
 return [
   ...(cssBundleHref
  ? [{ rel: "stylesheet", href: cssBundleHref }]
  : []),
  // ...
 ];
};
```

you can also reference [To use the built-in CSS Modules support, first ensure you've set up CSS bundling in your application](https://remix.run/docs/en/1.19.3/guides/styling#css-bundling)